Relation between hfe value of transistor and Vce
EXPLANATION
Sometimes some datasheets of transistor gives different Vce values for the hfe, but sometimes they just give hfe for single Vce.

For example, the hfe graph of  2SC2411K transistor is shown in Picture 1. Here we have 3 different Vce values so I can understand that hfe stays constant for the given Vce values, slightly changing at the end. Then I can interpret that the hfe will be more or less same for the Vce > 5 V.
However, let see the 2N3055 transistor as given in Picture 2. It has a hfe graph only for Vce= 4 V.

QUESTION

How should I interpret the 2N3055 graph? Should I follow the Vce=4 V graph for different kind of Vce values? This is what I understand from the graph because they gave only single Vce which is 4 V.

Picture 1. hf graph of 2SC2411K

Source: https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/bipolar/2sc2411k.pdf
Picture 2. hfe graph of 2N3055

Source:https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/2n3055-d.pdf


How should I interpret the 2N3055 graph ?

The same way you should interpret the graph of the hFE for any bipolar transistor.
Bipolar hFE is a poorly controlled, not very constant, value. You cannot rely on it having an exact value.
You can rely on the minimum guaranteed value, and design to that, while expecting a large variation in hFE. You cope with the hFE variation with feedback.
A graph of hFE will show you typically how non-constantly you should expect it to behave when things vary. In the case of the 2N3055 graph, hFE collapses slowly as the collector current increases above a few hundred mA.
The fact that the graph is drawn at a single voltage suggests that you would get a not-too-different graph at other voltages.
The fact that they show a large variation with temperature at low currents, and no temperature variation at around 5 A, tells you that you cannot apply any easy sort of temperature compensation to try to get a constant hFE.
If I recall my semiconductor physics courses correctly, the physical 'reason' for hFE is the thickness of the base region. When most transistors are made, this is a small difference between two big processing steps, and so is very poorly controlled, explaining the variation between individual transistors, and especially between batches and manufacturers. The 'effective' thickness changes with bias voltage, collector current and temperature, which is why hFE changes with those.

However, there is no need to be too concerned about the hfe variation. The voltage gain is only determined by the chosen collector current (or the resulting transconductance). The B value (or hfe) only determines the input resistance of the stage.

The first thing to note is that the 2SC2411K is a BJT whose maximum dissipated power is 200mW and is used in switching or as a small signal amplifier, so it is important for the study of polarization to know the static common-emitter current gain for various Vce voltages. The 2N3055 transistor has a maximum power of 115 Watts, with an average hFE current gain of 45. It is used in the final stages of amplifiers and mostly as a power buffer. Given the high collector and therefore base currents, it is often driven by another BJT in Darlington configuration. This results in a strong power dissipation in the form of heat which results in a variation of the hFE, so it is good to know the trend of hFE for different temperatures as the collector current and Vce voltage vary


How should I interpret the 2N3055 graph?

If you dig a little deeper and find an older data sheet, it will give you some idea about how hFE changes with collector-emitter voltage rather than interpreting the graph. For instance: -

This is an image of the graph from the original RCA 2N3055 taken from this site. Scroll down to see it and others.

Should I follow the Vce=4 V graph for different kind of Vce values?

As you can see, for a given base current (say 100 mA) the collector current remains constant for collector-emitter voltages from below 4 volts to above 50 volts. Of course, virtually any similarly rated BJT will be the same in the active region so, it shouldn't really be a surprise.
The bottom line:
If base current is constant and, collector current is constant then, hFE is constant.

You should plot (simulation) these curves to see what happens.
Here is the results (beta=dIc/dIb vs Ic) with microcap v12.
Note the "reduction" versus the Ic current.

How should I interpret the 2N3055 graph?
Should I follow the Vce=4 V graph for different kind of Vce values?

Beta is quasi "proportional" to Vce.

